'AuthorizedSession' object error when trying to pass in a google worksheet to a function via multiprocessing
def foo(args):
    print("before")

    logs = args[0]
    print(logs)

    logs.append_row(["testing"])

def mpfunc1(logs):
    args = [(logs,)]
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        pool.map_async(foo, args).get()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    g_sheet_logs, g_sheet_db = access_google_sheets("test_sheet")
    mpfunc1(g_sheet_logs)

    print("Finished")

I have the following python code, which takes a google worksheet object that was opened with gspread in access_google_sheets. I'm trying to pass it into the foo() function which is called under mpfunc1(). I know the worksheet is getting passed into foo() since I'm able to print it, but when I try to use .append_row() to the worksheet it raises the following error:
AttributeError: 'AuthorizedSession' object has no attribute '_auth_request'
If I try to append a row to the worksheet in mpfunc1() though, it works fine. I'm not sure why this is happening, and I'm wondering if there's a better solution to this than to redefine the worksheet in foo() by calling access_google_sheets() again.
